# ClassCastException only when runing java project without gwt debug

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, maven, classcastexception

i would like to know if someone already had this kind of javascript error :

In Chrome Console :

```
Uncaught java.lang.ClassCastException (anonymous function)
EED997003B4F236C1F5D6AE53E1170DA.cache.html:1624
```

Using Firefox :

```
CallPageHandler method : 
'java.lang.ClassCastException' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]
```

Considering that when i execute my project in debug mode (gwt eclipse plugin + plugin chrome browser) i have 0 error/warning. So the previous error only occurs without the use of gwt debug (project is successfuly build with maven).

I have checked my client side sources several times to find a probable error but i found nothing...

Maybe my configuration of gwt plugin in pom file is not correct (and could be an explanation of the different behaviour between debug and no-debug mode) :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
                        <module>[myMainClass]</module>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

- I'm using 2.4.0 gwt version and 2.0 maven plugin.

Thx for u help and i can give more detail if necessary !

```
>>> Resolved (see comments...) <<<
```

Comment: did you try to compile in [DETAILED style](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#style) ? It might help you to debug the javascript.

Comment: Ok i fixed my pb :
so the only error went from my client code when i tried to create an object with a bad constructor (but i haven't seen it before because it was in a separated library project).

@Gontard : i wrote some try catch block (class cast) to locate the bugged part of code ! Detailed debug js console ! i have to try this next time thx :D

To conclude : ClassCastException is unequivocal no need to search something else :P